# Kendo Export to PDF too Slow

Tags: pdf, kendo-ui, grid, export

I am facing two different problems when pressing  the export to PDF button external to the Kendo Grid (We are using : kendo.web.min v2015.2.624  and pako_deflate.min 2015.2.624 to enable compression in the PDF - we are using local data)

1- The time it takes to export data to PDF is almost 10 times the excel export for the same set of data.

2- Firefox is giving the warning dialog box that the script is unresponsive.

thanks

Comment: Getting the same issue on a report with a lot of data.  Would love to see an answer to this.
PDF renders the HTML from the page, so it makes sense it would take longer than Excel.  
Various reports with less data work fine, but there looks to be a tipping point.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to generate file on the server side... There is a limit of items number that can be exported successfully for every browser
http://www.telerik.com/forums/all-page-pdf-export-in-chrome
I faced with the same problem in FF, Chrome limit is greater as I see